# How to Setup and check if cron jobs are running on ec2 instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I am running a Linux instance on ec2 I need a cron job to run every minute

When I use crontab in the terminal ( i am logged in using the terminal btw ) it does not seem to be working and when I use the cron.d option it does not seem to be working either

```
cron.d file * * * * * ec2-user python3 /home/ec2-user/Programs/file.py
```

this does not seem to work and I'm out of ideas if somebody could walk me threw the process of creating a cron on ec2 that would be really helpful

Comment: Have you started the cron service...try `sudo service crond start` ?

Comment: just ran it nothing happens

Comment: Does that file exist? and what it does? perhaps checking the logs would give you a clue..

Comment: How Can i check the logs ?

Comment: Its in the /var/log/syslog file

Comment: i cant find the syslog file in there it does not  even appear

Comment: what's the linux dist you are using?

Comment: its the amazon ami instance

Comment: No I mean the linux distro name..can you run the following command and see what output you get? `cat /etc/*-release`

Comment: what part are you looking for is it the id_like part ? Thats fedora

Comment: run `systemctl status crond.service` to see if crond is running. if not you need to start it.

Comment: systemctl is not found

Comment: when i just run status crond.service it says uknown job

Answer (score 0):

To check to see if the cron daemon is running, search the running processes with the ps command.  The cron daemon's command will show up in the output as crond.

```
$ ps -ef | grep crond

root      2560     1  0 07:37 ?        00:00:00 crond
oracle    2953  2714  0 07:53 pts/0    00:00:00 grep crond
```

The entry in this output for grep crond can be ignored but the other entry for crond can be seen running as root.  This shows that the cron daemon is running.